# Unit of Work - Erro: "Attaching an entity of type 'EntityB' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Essas são minhas classes de exemplo:

```
public class EntityA
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public decimal AproveValue { get; set; }
  public string EntityB_Id { get; set; }
  public virtual EntityB EntityBs { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public decimal Name { get; set; }
}
```

Essa é a minha classe de repositório:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
   _myDbSet.Attach(entity);
   ((IObjectContextAdapter)MyContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
}
```

Eu uso o padrão Unit Of Work para gerenciar o contexto.

Quando eu tento atualizar a propriedade EntityA.AproveValue e chamo o método de update do repositório, na linha _myDbSet.Attach(entity) é lançado esse erro:

```
Attaching an entity of type 'EntityB' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. 
This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.
```

Eu já tentei fazer assim:

```
MyContext.Entry(model.EntityB).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
base.Update(model);
```

Mas não funcionou!

Eu preciso manter a propriedade navegável.

E esse problema acontece com todas as propriedades navegáveis do projeto.

Comment: já tentou "atachar" as entidades? pelo seu modelo, me parece que a EntityA precisa ser atachada à EntityB, algo assim: `MyContext.Attach(model.EntityB)`

Comment: Sim, coloquei no update antes de atachar a entityA, mas deu o mesmo erro. Vou tentar uma outra solução se der certo posto aqui o resultado